# Powershell Installing an EXE that hangs

Tags: powershell, exe

Hi I am trying to make a script so that I can install the Dell Display Manager on any computer that I choose. I copy the install from our network location to the user's local storage, install it, and then remove the file after. I can see the process running in task manager but it seems to not do anything. I don't know if this is because the installer has prompts that need to be checked or what? Any help?

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Computer Name you are accessing'

#Move/Install On PC#

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\c$\TempInstall"

Copy-Item "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test\DisplayManager.exe" "\\$Computer\c$\TempInstall" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

$e = test-path -Path "\\$Computer\c$\TempInstall\DisplayManger.exe"
    IF ($e -eq 'True') {write-host "Transfer completed" -ForegroundColor red} ELSE {write-host "File not found"}

Write-Host "Installling Display Manger on $Computer"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "C:\TempInstall\DisplayManager.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /v/qn" -Wait} 

#Remove files#

Write-Host "Removing Temporary files on $Computer"
$RemovalPath = "\\$Computer\c$\TempInstall"
Remove-Item $RemovalPath -Force
$f = test-path -Path "\\$Computer\c$\TempInstall\DisplayManger.exe"
    IF ($f -eq 'False') {write-host "File Removed" -ForegroundColor red} ELSE {write-host ""}
```

Comment: `"/S /v/qn"` looks like you are missing a space before /qn

Comment: Good eye, but that doesn't change the outcome

Comment: Then it's possibly showing an error message. Does the installer have a parameter to enable logging?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors. Just keeps running the script but nothing ever happens. Not that I know of but I am not sure how I would check if it enabled logging?

Comment: Try to run the installer locally with parameter /? to see if it has a parameter to set log path.

Comment: Perhaps try `Start-Process` with `cmd /c ...`

Comment: I ran it with Start-Process and cmd /c and it at least finished running the script but the install doesn't actually do anything which is weird to me. I tried to specify a log path but the file doesn't get created.